# Use MongoDB as internal analytics tools

Tags: mongodb

all
I was reading a real-world system design doc
http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/3/16/justintvs-live-video-broadcasting-architecture.html?lastPage=true&postSubmitted=true

Important detail is

1.MongoDB - used for their internal analytics tools.

2.They have added monitoring to everything. Every click, page view, and action is measured to help improve service. Log messages from the front-end, web call, or from an application server are converted to syslog messages and forwarded through syslog-ngto a single log host. They scan through the data, load it into MongoDB, and run queries on MongoDB.

Q:
It mentioned that MongoDB is used for store monitoring message.
Why we use MongoDB here? I know MongoDB is best for document-store.
So is industry logging message a document format?

Comment: A log object or message can be a document part of the logging collection.